# TSQL -- Inserting Dates Into Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, datetime, date, dynamic-sql

Consider the following TSQL:

```
SET @WhereClause1 = 'where a.Date > ' + @InvoiceDate
```

I get a date/string conversion error.  `@InvoiceDate` is a datetime variable.  What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might work.

```
SET @WhereClause1 = 'where a.Date > ''' + convert(varchar, @InvoiceDate) + ''''
```

although an error will be raised if the value is null.

Comment: this doesn't work because you have to enclosed the date (inside the string) with quotation marks

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
SET @WhereClause1 = 'where a.Date > ''' + cast(@InvoiceDate as varchar(100)) + ''''
```

Comment: i wish I could mark two answers approved because this one works too.  thanks

Comment: When I have that trouble, I select one and give points (arrow up) to the others (if they are more than 1). That doesn't mean you have to do the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your composing query as a string first, then I think you need to convert @InvoiceDate to a string with something like [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2197931_1/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Two---Displaying-Dates-and-Times-in-Different-Formats.htm). http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2197931_1/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Two---Displaying-Dates-and-Times-in-Different-Formats.htm

Answer (score 1):

... and you will probably need to enclose date strings in quotes.

It would probably actually be better to construct the date string in the calling routine because you should be checking there for null values and maybe other validations.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE a.Date > @date',
                   N'@date datetime',
                   @date = @InvoiceDate
```